# Colab run time stays "Busy" state after restarting the run time

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I have legacy code which uses **tensorflow 1.0.1** version in my ipython notebook.
I have a *requirements.txt* file to install dependencies.
So I run the cell -`!pip3 install -r requirements.txt` in my Colab notebook to run this legacy code.

*requirements.txt* has following dependencies,

- tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1
- nltk==3.2.5
- matplotlib==2.0.2
- scipy==0.19.1
- scikit-learn==0.19.0
- jupyter==1.0.0

After running the above cell in my notebook I get a message to restart the runtime to setup the environment for TensorFlow 1.0.1. 
After restarting the kernel I always get the runtime in the "Busy" state.

Even though I tried terminating the session to start again. It does not help because I have to restart the kernel in new session too.

Can anyone clarify what should I do to avoid "staying Busy state" after kernel restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the jupyter install. It's likely that's installing deps that are incompatible with Colab, which results in your backend becoming wedged.

When in this state, you can reset your runtime using the Runtime -> Factory reset runtime menu.

Comment: Removing jupyter dependency led me to restart the kernel and move on. (It did not stay at "Busy" state) :)